# Как получить нужное значение из json

Tags: java, json

В java нужно инициализировать class  значениями из One и Two или такими же из AAA

```
public final class setting{
  boolean flag = true;
  String one;
  long two;
}
```

JsonObject response содержит

```
{
"One": "text", "Two": 111111,
"AAA": {"One": "text2", "Two": 222222}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Подключите либу Gson

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

2. Исправьте класс так, чтобы имена полей совпадали с именами полей JSON (или вопользуйтесь аннотациями для задавания имён полей)

```
public class Setting {
  @SerializedName("One")
  String one;
  @SerializedName("Two")
  long two;
}
```

2. Создайте экземпляр класса из JSON так:

```
String json = "{\"One\":\"text2\", \"Two\":222222}"

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
Setting setting = gson.fromJson(json , Setting.class);
```

Comment: Объект уже есть JsonObject response а в квадратных скобках его содержимое, нужно в зависимости от флага допустим boolean two = true выбрать значения из ААА а если флаг false то из AAA трогать не нужно уже есть if (response.containsKey("One"))
     Setting.one= response.getJsonNumber("One").longValue(); Как сделать тоже из AAA

Comment: @S.Oleg, согласно этому валидатору у вас не JSON http://jsonlint.com/ Если бы был обычный JSON, то можно было бы парспарсить его gson-ом в два объекта, один вложен в другой и далее делать с ними всё что угодно. Пока что суть ваших затруднений не ясна